# Keepass FileZilla AutoType

Tags: keepass

I am currently setting up Keepass with all my FTP credentials and I am trying to keep it simple as possible.

So I tried to set up the AutoType functionality. But I am currently struggling with opening Filezilla automatically and adding the credentials without clicking on the input field itself.

Is there a way how can I achieve this or is there an alternative for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open Filezilla. The cursor will be in the "server" field.

Now as autotype, change it to

```
ftp://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{URL}{ENTER}
```

For unencrypted ftp, for example. The URL must be in following format to work, where port is an option.

```
servername.tld[:port]
```

In my german version, I would need to add "alt+R", but focus was on the server field in my case.

If you move your mouse over the server field, you will see how to connect to sftp.

Comment: The question was how to do this automatically, including the filezilla start.

Answer (score 3):

The way I use it and as alternative to autotype is using the open URL shortcut & applying a URL override. This way, I only have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and FileZilla automatically opens and connects immediately.

To set up in KeePass:

- go to "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Integration" tab -> "URL Overrides" (bottom right button)
- add an override for ftp and/or sftp with the override as below (*in Windows, other paths:* https://github.com/kvaps/keepass-url-overrides#ftp):

  > cmd://"C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe "{URL}
- Create a new entry

  - Enter in the URL field:

    > ftp://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{TITLE}
  - put the URL of the ftp address in the title field
  - put the user name in the username field
  - put the password in password field
- Save
- Select the new entry and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- FileZilla should open and connect immediately

For an `sftp` connection use this in the URL field:

> sftp://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{TITLE}:22

You can tweak it with what is allowed by FileZilla's command line: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way that lets you use the URL and title fields normally:

On the Integrations tab, add URL overrides for ftp and sftp:

`ftp`:

```
cmd://"C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe" ftp://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{URL:RMVSCM}
```

`sftp`:

```
cmd://"C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe" sftp://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{URL:RMVSCM}
```

Comment: I dont have any tab named integration in my entries. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: The tab is called Properties. There is the field Override URL to be filled with one of the entries you posted. Only one is allowed though.

Comment: I found the integration tab. You can find it in the menu Tools => Options => Integration => URL Overrides